# How to get and kill the process Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

1. Find specific client with name and memory
2. Get the client pId
3. Kill pId

Can I do kill that process just within the terminal.

What I tried

```
ps aux | grep leagueClientUxHelper | awk '{print $2}'
```

but I can't get the large memory process.

Same process names in activated status:

[image: same process names in activated status]

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a process with the id by using the kill command.

```
ps aux | grep TextEdit | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

That will pipe it directly into the kill command.  You will get an error because the ps aux will show two PIDs but it won't cause any problems.

Kill only works with PIDs

Are you trying to drill down to a certain memory length or compared to another instance like league1 memory is > leage2 memory?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to kill the largest one. I'm not sure about the memory length.